# Swagger UI forces "required" on parameter

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui

I've got 2 similiar endpoints.

```
@GetMapping("/api/entity")
@SecurityRequirement(name = "Basic Authentication")
public List<EntityResponseDTO> getAll() { return entityService.getEntities(); }

@GetMapping("/api/entity")
public List<EntityResponseDTO> getAllInCity(@RequestParam("city") String city) { return entityService.getEntities(city); }
```

I'm also using Swagger in order to generate API documentation. The issue with these 2 endpoints is that Swagger does not really recognize the 1st one. Or, to be more precise, it connects them.

When I open up Swagger UI, I see only one of them:
`GET /api/entity`. It is both secured (as the 1st mapping has `@SecurityRequirement`) and parameterized (2nd's `@RequestParam`). The issue is that the parameter is set to `required` in the UI and I can't set it otherwise. I've tried the `@Parameter` annotation, but can't seem to get it working.

I'd like to be able to - in Swagger UI, obviously - query for all entities as authorized user and query for all entities in a city as not logged-in user.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `@RequestParam`'s `required` field to false solves this issue.

EDIT: The endpoint looks like this right now:

```
@GetMapping("/api/entity")
public List<EntityResponseDTO> getAllInCity(@RequestParam(value = "city", required = false) String city) { return entityService.getEntities(city); }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution.